# Getting canvas data without using canvas.toDataURL?

Tags: image, canvas

I'm making a painting application but the browser I want it to work (Nintendo 3DS Browser) doesn't support canvas.toDataURL.

I know it's possible getting the canvas data without canvas.toDataURL, because Robdeprop (creator of 3DSPlaza.com) created a painting application for the Nintendo 3DS Browser.

I asked how, and he replied

> The 3DS does not support the functions to get the canvas data. Well
>   then, how do I do it? Every time a line is drawn I save the begin
>   coordinates and end coordinates of that line to an array. When the
>   user hits save, I convert that array to a string and send it to a PHP
>   file as POST parameter. In the PHP file I convert the string back to
>   an array. Then I use the PHP GD functions to draw each line on an
>   image. Then I save the image. imagecreatetruecolor, imageline and
>   imagepng is all you need I think.

But I have no idea how to do this... any help?
Thanks in advance..

I'm new here so please don't down note ;-;

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/todataurl-png-js/

It may be for Android but it worth a shot.